# How do I add gap between the two boxes?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to add gap between two black boxes in the scroll able area as you can see in the picture. The gap should be such that the background image can be seen. I tried using `pady` command but gray background is coming. How can I fix it?

[Image 1: This is how it currently is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JZTz.png)

[Image 2: This is how I want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlxlt.jpg)

[[Image 3: This is how it is with pady]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNMLq.png)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

C = Tk()
C.geometry("1100x660")

BG = PhotoImage(file="HUD.png")
IMG_BG=PhotoImage(file="0001.png")
ML=PhotoImage(file="SongDisplay_BG.png")
AddSongButton = PhotoImage(file="Add song.png")
FolderButton=PhotoImage(file="Add from folder.png")
GoOnlineButton=PhotoImage(file="Go Online.png")
Love=PhotoImage(file="Love.png")
Party=PhotoImage(file="Party.png")
Sleep=PhotoImage(file="Sleep.png")
Workout=PhotoImage(file="Workout.png")


HUD_BG = Label(C, image=BG, border=0)
HUD_BG.place(x=0, y=0)
IBG = Label(C, image=IMG_BG, border=0)
IBG.place(x=301, y=0)

#Window_Buttons
Add_Song_btn = Button(C, image=AddSongButton, border=0,bg="#0D0D0D", activebackground="#0D0D0D", command="")
Add_Song_btn.place(x=25, y=134)

Add_from_Folder_btn = Button(C, image=FolderButton, border=0,bg="#0D0D0D", activebackground="#0D0D0D", command="")
Add_from_Folder_btn.place(x=25, y=176)

Go_Online_btn = Button(C, image=GoOnlineButton, border=0,bg="#0D0D0D", activebackground="#0D0D0D", command="")
Go_Online_btn.place(x=25, y=218)

#Playlist
Love_btn = Button(C, image=Love, border=0,bg="#0D0D0D", activebackground="#0D0D0D", command="")
Love_btn.place(x=25, y=350)

Party_btn = Button(C, image=Party, border=0,bg="#0D0D0D", activebackground="#0D0D0D", command="")
Party_btn.place(x=25, y=392)

Sleep_btn = Button(C, image=Sleep, border=0,bg="#0D0D0D", activebackground="#0D0D0D", command="")
Sleep_btn.place(x=25, y=434)

Workout_btn = Button(C, image=Workout, border=0,bg="#0D0D0D", activebackground="#0D0D0D", command="")
Workout_btn.place(x=25, y=476)


style.configure("Vertical.TScrollbar", gripcount=0,
                background="#65EBDC", darkcolor="#AB83FF", lightcolor="#AB83FF",
                troughcolor="#A88CFF", bordercolor="#AB83FF", arrowcolor="Black",arrowsize=15)

wrapper1= LabelFrame(C, width="1900", height="100", background="Blue",bd=0)
mycanvas = Canvas(wrapper1,background="Blue",borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, width=750, height=490)
mycanvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand=False, padx=0)
Label2= Label(mycanvas, image=IMG_BG, border=0)
Label2.place(x=0,y=0)

yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(wrapper1, orient="vertical",command=mycanvas.yview)
yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill="y", expand = False)


mycanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

mycanvas.bind('<Configure>',lambda e: mycanvas.configure(scrollregion=mycanvas.bbox("all")))
myframe = Frame(mycanvas)
Label1= Label(myframe)

mycanvas.create_window((0,0), window=myframe, anchor="nw")

wrapper1.place(x =315, y =50)

for i in range(50):
    L1=Button(myframe, image= ML, border=0,activebackground="#0C374A",background="#0C374A").grid(row=i, pady=5)


mainloop()
```

**EDIT**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

C = Tk()
C.geometry("1100x660")

BG = PhotoImage(file="HUD.png")
IMG_BG=PhotoImage(file="0001.png")
ML=PhotoImage(file="SongDisplay_BG.png")


HUD_BG = Label(C, image=BG, border=0)
HUD_BG.place(x=0, y=0)
IBG = Label(C, image=IMG_BG, border=0)
IBG.place(x=301, y=0)

wrapper1= LabelFrame(C, width="1900", height="100",bd=0)
mycanvas = Canvas(wrapper1,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, width=750, height=490)
mycanvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand=False, padx=0)
Label2= Label(mycanvas, image=IMG_BG, border=0)
Label2.place(x=0,y=0)

yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(wrapper1, orient="vertical",command=mycanvas.yview)
yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill="y", expand = False)


mycanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

mycanvas.bind('<Configure>',lambda e: mycanvas.configure(scrollregion=mycanvas.bbox("all")))
myframe = Frame(mycanvas,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, width=750, height=490)
Label1= Label(myframe)

wrapper1.place(x =315, y =50)

for i in range(50):
    L1=Button(myframe, image= ML,  border=0,activebackground="#0C374A",background="#0C374A").grid(row=i, pady=5)
    
mycanvas.create_window((0,0), window=myframe, anchor="nw")

mainloop()
```

I want to remove those white spaces between two buttons.

[HUD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqFGH.png)

[0001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXY30.png)

[SongDisplay_BG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJJMz.png)

Comment: You need to put those black buttons inside canvas using `create_window()` directly instead of putting them inside the internal frame (`myframe`).  In this case, the internal frame is not necessary.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create an example that doesn't use images, since we can't run your code as-is.

Comment: @acw1668 Placing them in ```canvas``` makes the area unscrollable.

Comment: @BryanOakley Would it be any helpful if I would upload those images too?

Comment: Unless the images are part of the problem, it's more helpful to modify the code to not need the images.

Comment: @BryanOakley The images are kind of important and without that it is not possible to exactly show what the problem is. So I have made the code as minimal as possible by keeping only 3 images[images provided too], it would be very helpful if you helped. Please check the edit section.